# Alternative to UIDate picker - better UI element for picking Date and Time.

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4

I just HATE the UIDate and Time Picker that Apple supplies. Do you know of any other library that creates an equivalent UI element for picking time and date, that can be better customized at least? I'd hate to rediscover the weel.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for any others wondering about my conclusions... 
I think it would look better to use a calendar to pick the date and keep a picker for the time so far.

For calendar there is a good implementation here:
https://github.com/klazuka/Kal